# Revolution Slider - How to Serve Resources from a Consistent URL

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting "Serve resources from a consistent URL" error whenever i analyze my website on GTmetrix, how do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install this plugin:

> WP Remove Query Strings From Static Resources

Then go to ./wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes directory and edit output.class.php. Search for

> revolution.tools.min.js?ver='.$slver.'">

and replace it as

> revolution.tools.min.js">

Do the same thing for `rs6.min.js` too.

Comment: Will this edit not be lost when we upgrade Revslider to the latest version ?

Comment: @Mihaela Probably. Definitely, if they make any changes on rs6.min.js or output.class.php. All you need to do is to repeat these steps and it should be ok.